# Adding a new method to an existing (standard) type

Tags: go

I'm writing some code that needs functionality that is almost satisfied by the `ReadBytes` method in the `bufio` package. Specifically, that method reads from a `Reader` until it encounters a particular byte. I need something that reads till it encounters one out of couple of bytes (space, newline and tab mainly).

I looked at the source for the library and I know what to do if I have access to the internal buffer used by `bufio` structs. Is there any way I could "monkey patch" the package and add another method or two to it? Or another way to get the functionality I need?

Comment: A major reason there are private hidden fields is to make it possible for the implementation to evolve in the future without impacting users. Allowing you to access byte would break this guarantee. So I don't see other proper way than to make your own (limited) Reader struct and method.

Comment: Your question is about one solution (enhancing bufio) you have in mind for your real problem (reading a certain data format.)  As the answers and comments indicate, the package features of Go were actually engineered to obstruct you from doing that.  It might be better to consider other solutions, or even post another question on SO with details of your data format and ask, "what's a good way of reading this multiple-delimiter format?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along this approach (caution: untested code):

```
type reader struct{
        *bufio.Reader // 'reader' inherits all bufio.Reader methods
}

func newReader(rd io.Reader) reader {
        return reader{bufio.NewReader(rd)}
}

// Override bufio.Reader.ReadBytes
func (r reader) ReadBytes(delim byte) (line []byte, err error) {
        // here goes the monkey patch
}

// Or

// Add a new method to bufio.Reader
func (r reader) ReadBytesEx(delims []byte) (line []byte, err error) {
        // here goes the new code
}
```

EDIT: I should have noted that this *doesn't* help to access the original package internals (non exported entities). Thanks Abhay for pointing that out in your comment.

Comment: Can you access the unexported fields of bufio.Reader this way ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this seems to result in the calls being delegated to the inner struct. The whole struct is still embedded in the new one and is still treated like a separate entity. You don't actually have access to it's package local variables. Thanks for the attempt though!

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best to solve problems using the package API.  If you have a compelling reason to access unexported features though, copy the package source and hack it up.  The BSD-style license as about as liberal as they come.